# Dont use beforeunload on clicking a specific element (jquery, js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explain me, how to improve my code, so that it will:

1. Not call `beforeunload` event if I'll click on button with class
   `.btn`?
2. And, if it's possible, without tracking each click event.

I mean:

```
$(document).on("click", ....);
```

Here's my current code. It's working, but it prevents page reloading on each action (`close`, `back`, `click` on any button etc)

```
var reload = $(document).find("[data-prevent-reload]");

if(reload.data('prevent-reload')) {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (ev) {
    return ev.returnValue = 'STOP!';
  });
}
```

Comment: related: https://questions/18783535/jquery-beforeunload-when-closing-not-leaving-the-page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no event that tells you what triggered it so you are stuck with listening to the click events. It is normally done with boolean and check it before calling it.

```js
var ignoreUnload
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
   ignoreUnload = true
});

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (ev) {
  if(!ignoreUnload) return ev.returnValue = 'STOP!';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" href="https://example.com">btn</a>
<a class="" href="https://example.com">not</a>
```

other option could be to unbind the event instead of the boolean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Whent i wrote about click listeners, i forgot, that i can use it for specific class and not for all page. Again thank you!